React Native File Upload returns 400
Native project that upload file. My submit function does not upload file and image. Whenever I try to upload document it returns 200 and everything is okay but whenever I try to upload image it returns 400. Surprisingly, when I try to upload image via POSTMAN it returns 200.
Let me share some code.
const submit = async () => {
try {
loadingStore.setLoading(true);
var response;
var fileStream: FileStreamData = {
position: 0,
readTimeout: 0,
writeTimeout: 0,
};
var uploadFile: UploadFile = {
FileStream : fileStream,
fileName: isDocument ? documentName : imageName,
fileData: byteArrayData,
mimeType: documentType,
size: documentSize,
documentTypeCode: '',
fileExtension: 'jpg',
};
var vacationData: IVacationUploadFileData = {
perRef: userPerRef,
perCode: '',
code: '',
description: description,
address: address,
vacTypeRef: dropDownValue,
begDate: moment(startDateTime).format(),
endDate: moment(endDateTime).format(),
returnDate: returnDate,
period: period,
periodTime: '',
periodTypeId: 0,
statusId: 0,
startTime: '08:00:00',
endTime: '08:00:00',
trType: 0,
uploadFile,
documentUrl: '',
jpFirmId: 1,
jpObjectState: '',
logicalRef: 0,
};
if (openMode === OpenMode.Create) {
response = await api.vacations.create(vacationData);
}

      loadingStore.setLoading(false);
    
      if (!response.data.success) {
        Toast.Error('Error', response.data?.errors[0]);
        return;
      }
      Toast.Success('Success', 'Successfully Added!');
      setDocumentName('');
      setImageName('');
      setTimeout(() => {
        navigation.goBack();
      }, 1000);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error : ', error);
    }

}; 

`create(vacationData: IVacationUploadFileData) {         console.log('Creating vacation with data:', vacationData);         return $axios.post<IResponse<IVacations[]>>('/api/services/app/TDVVacationInformation/CreateOrEdit', {             perRef: vacationData.perRef,             perCode: vacationData.perCode,             code: vacationData.code,             description: vacationData.description,             address: vacationData.address,             vacTypeRef: vacationData.vacTypeRef,             begDate: vacationData.begDate,             endDate: vacationData.endDate,             returnDate: vacationData.returnDate,             period: vacationData.period,             periodTime: vacationData.periodTime,             periodTypeId: vacationData.periodTypeId,             statusId: vacationData.statusId,             startTime: vacationData.startTime,             endTime: vacationData.endTime,             trType: vacationData.trType,             uploadFile: vacationData.uploadFile,             documentUrl: vacationData.documentUrl,             jpFirmId: vacationData.jpFirmId,             jpObjectState: vacationData.jpObjectState,             logicalRef: vacationData.logicalRef         });     }`

in case you want to see my base64toByteArray function ;
const base64ToByteArray = base64 => {     const binaryString = atob(base64);     const byteArray = new Uint8Array(binaryString.length);     for (let i = 0; i < binaryString.length; i++) {       byteArray[i] = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);     }     return byteArray;   };

Any suggestion appreciated!
I tried to log everything and use logged data via POSTMAN before and after response.

(Given the initial code layout, at least the last two code blocks are hard to read.)
